# Can't install QT4 on Ubuntu due to ssl issue

Tags: qt, ubuntu, ssl, embedded, qt4

I'm trying to install QT4 (32bits) on an ubuntu VirtualBox (64bits). 
I struggle with the installation because of a ssl error that I can't get rid off ...

Here is what I did :

- I downloaded the qt-everywhere-opensource-4.8.7.tar.gz archive
- I extracted it
- Inside the folder I type this command :

```
./configure -debug -embedded generic -platform linux-g++-32 -xplatform linux-g++-32 -depths 16 -no-accessibility -no-qt3support -no-glib -qt-gfx-vnc -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-javascript-jit -prefix "/usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.7-x86/" -no-script -no-scripttools -no-declarative -no-svg -no-webkit -no-libtiff -no-gif -no-libmng -qt-libpng -system-libjpeg -no-xmlpatterns -no-sql-db2 -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-oci -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-sqlite_symbian -no-sql-tds -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-psql -no-sql-sqlite -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-exceptions -no-stl -nomake demos -nomake examples -no-cups -no-iconv -no-nis -openssl -opensource -confirm-license -qvfb -no-declarative-debug
```

- Then I type `make` but I have the error :

```
Makefile:18201: recipe for target '.obj/debug-shared-emb-x86/qsslsocket_openssl.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [.obj/debug-shared-emb-x86/qsslsocket_openssl.o] Error 1
    make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/jerome/Documents/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7/src/network »
    Makefile:267: recipe for target 'sub-network-make_default-ordered' failed
    make: *** [sub-network-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Here are the packages I've got that could be interesting :

[image: Ssl packages]
[image: gcc and g++ packages]
I know this problem could be related to libssl version but I tried to install older version, 64 or 32 bits but I still have this error ...

I would strongly appreciate some help on this !

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried the installation while not passing all those flags on a copy of your VM? You are disabling **a lot**.

Comment: Yes I did, I had the same error. 
I found the solution and I shared it. But thanks for trying to help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution !
The problem didn't come from `libsll`, but it was related to `openssl` version.

The version 1.1.1 was installed (as we can see on the first screen). 
So I renamed the executable `/usr/bin/openssl` as `/usr/bin/openssl.1.1.1` and I installed an older version of openssl (1.0.2) :

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz 
tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2l 
sudo ./config
sudo make install
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

And that's it ! I checked the version by typing `openssl version` and it returned `1.0.2` !

Then QT4 compiled just fine !